# How does node.js configurable logger work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading a book called Node.js in Action by Nike Cantelon and stuck at a configurable logger implementation:

**when using String.prototype.replace() we set a function(match, property) as a second parameter and I am clueless about what it does**. Could anyone explain what function(match, property) does? The way code is written doesn't give me an insight into that..

```
function setup(format){
let regex = /:(\w+)/g;
return function logger(req, res, next){
      let str = format.replace(regex, (match, property) => {
          return req[property];
      });
      console.log(str);
      next();
  }
}

module.exports = setup;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String.replace() function takes two arguments: `searchvalue` and `newvalue`. This means that you are searching for a particular pattern in your `format` string. When found, it is replaced by the value of `req[property]`. So the function is getting the `property` as it's argument, then uses it as a key for `req` object, getting the value back and replacing the found appearance in `format` string.

Comment: Now I get the gist, but still have know idea of what `match` does. Could you give some details about `match`?

Comment: You can learn about the function arguments [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), it is well documented.